# Android service - keep checking the current time if it match a saved time

Tags: android, service

My Android service has to keep checking if the current time is matching a saved time. I used a service which has a timer that every minute checks if the current time is matching the saved time. If Android goes to sleep mode, he stops checking. I tried WakeLocker for this problem. It works, but it drains my battery.

The code I'm currently using is as follow.

```
    public class AlarmService extends Service {

    private static Timer timer = new Timer(); 
    private Context ctx;
    private WakeLock wakeLock;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The new Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onCreate();
        ctx = this; 
        startService();

        /* Wake locker
        PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Wake locker");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        */

    }

    private void startService()
    {           
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new mainTask(), 0, 60000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private class mainTask extends TimerTask
    { 
        public void run() 
        {
            toastHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }  

    private final Handler toastHandler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam"));
            Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
            DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", new Locale("nl", "nl"));
            date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam")); 
                String currenttime = date.format(currentLocalTime); 

                DateFormat date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", new Locale("nl", "nl"));
                date2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam")); 
                    String currentday = date2.format(currentLocalTime); 

            if(currentday.equals("maandag")) { // "maandag" is dutch for Monday
                String tijd1 = "16:00";

                if(currenttime.equals(tijd1)) {
                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
                            new NotificationCompat.Builder(AlarmService.this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle("Test message") .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setContentText("This is a test message");
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(AlarmService.this, MainActivity.class);
                    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(AlarmService.this);
                    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
                    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) AlarmService.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

                }                
            }
        }
    }; 
}
```

Does somebody have a solution for this problem, which doesn't drain my battery? So it has to check if the current time is matching the saved time, even when Android is sleeping.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an AlarmManager to schedule a block of code to run when you want to.

You'll need an AlarmManager and a class which extends BroadcastReceiver. Then override the onReceive() method and put in there the code you want to run. The device will wake up only for the duration of the onReceive() method inside your receiver.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) //Please note that context is "this" if you are inside an Activity

Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
PendingIntent event = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millisToFireEvent, event);
```